# How to detect changes to the text box and enable the save changes button

Tags: javascript

I need your help.

What would be the best & most form field efficient way to detect a change in a textbox?

Once a change to any of the textboxes has been made, the "save changes" button should be enabled.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="txt1" value="text1"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txt2" value="text2"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txt3" value="text3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="txt4" value="text4"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txt5" value="text5"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txt6" value="text6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="txt7" value="text7"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txt8" value="text8"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txt9" value="text9"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="save changes" disabled>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure JS approach:

```
var textboxes = document.querySelectorAll("table tr td input");

for (var i = 0; i < textboxes.length; i++) {
    textboxes[i].onkeyup = function() {
        document.getElementById("save").disabled = false;
    }
}

document.getElementById("save").onclick = function() {
    //do stuff, and disabled
    this.disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: No jQuery libraries are required. Fast and easy approach.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this, in jQuery framework:

```
$("input[type=text]").change(function() {
    $("input[type=button]").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```